# Do I need a ssl certificate for testing with selenium via vps server?

Tags: ssl-certificate, vps, java, chrome, selenium

i am trying to Set up a vps Server with which i want to test Websites in the open Web by opening different chrome windows with the help of selenium.

Now i wonder if i need a ssl certificate for doing that, because i do not host a Website and i thought that i would only need a ssl certificate if i want to host a Website, or do i also need that certificate for casual browsing with my vps?

Thanks for every answer. :)

Comment: Does this host run any services that may have TLS encryption? If so, yes you need an x509 certificate.

Comment: No it doesnt  it only executes a Java file